# How to find the mapping tables in from the EF generated Classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a mvc 4 application which is entity framework database first based. Therefore lots of the classes are generated based on database tables via EF.

Currently, I created a method to retrive data from a table and display them in a dropdownlist, which works fine. However, I am thinking to modify that method to a generic type method, and passing the class type as the method parameter, and I would like c# code to find the mapping table in the database and retrive the data.

Following is my modified method
Thanks for your helps!

```
   public static SelectList FromDbTableToSelectList<T>() where T: class 
    {
        var db = new TableEntities();
        //find the mapping database table

        Dictionary<Guid, string> dic = db.MappingTable.ToDictionary(v => v.tableColumn1, v => v.tableColumn2);

        return new SelectList(dic, "Key", "Value");
    }
```

Comment: What is `db.MappingTable`?

Comment: @GertArnold db.MappingTable is a table in the database, which generates a class in the mvc application by entity framework database first model.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your what your code does. However, there is a trick to find mapping table name (`Entity Set Name` in EF glossary) of an entity.

Suppose that you have a table in your db named `Products`. If you create your model with the `Pluralize and singularize` option checked, EF will create an entity class named `Product`.

Then, whenever you perform a query, EF naming convention thinks that your table name is `dbo.Products`. This is a general rule - in fact a naming convention.

From the other hand, if you uncheck the `Pluralize and Singularize` option, EF creates an entity class named `Products` for you and in this case, the class an the table have same names.

So, according to the selection of `P&S` option, you can infer table names from entity names and you don't need any code for it...